# I don't understand why my list comprehension isn't working

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

It looks like its formulated properly (to my noob eyes) so I'm stumped.

The question is:

> Write a program that first gets a list of integers from input. That
> list is followed by two more integers representing lower and upper
> bounds of a range. Your program should output all integers from the
> list that are within that range (inclusive of the bounds).

Ex: If the input is:

```
25 51 0 200 33
0 50
```

the output is:

```
25 0 33
```

> The bounds are 0-50, so 51 and 200 are out of range and thus not
> output.
>
> For coding simplicity, follow each output integer by a space, even the
> last one. Do not end with newline.

''' Type your code here. '''

```
while True:
    userEntered = input().split()
    rangeCue = input().split()
    break



rangeList = sorted([int(x) for x in rangeCue])
newList =  [int(x) for x in userEntered if int(x) >= rangeList[0] or int(x) <= rangeList[1]]

print(newList)
```

My input:

Enter program input (optional)

```
25 51 0 200 33
0 50
```

Program output displayed here

```
[25, 51, 0, 200, 33]
```

Comment: Think about what it means for the number `x` to be `x >= 0` **or** `x <= 50`. Consider `x = 51`. Is `50 > 0`? Yes. Hence your statement is true...

Comment: Check your condition for the list comprehension.   all values given in your list satisfy that condition.

Comment: Aside: what’s the point of that `while` loop…?

Comment: The while loop is to continuously take user inputs. In the past, when I have just put one input(), the program has only taken one input rather than the several that I need.

Comment: But it doesn’t. You always `break` the loop immediately, so it never loops, so you might as well omit it entirely.

Comment: `if int(x) >= rangeList[0] or int(x) <= rangeList[1]` can be written as `if rangeList[0] <= int(x) <= rangeList[1]`.

Comment: @Matthias With the caveat that it becomes an `and` condition, which also fixes the problem…

Comment: @deceze Correct. I wanted to write the correct expression but I had an `OutOfCoffeeError`.